# Access database error "Could not find file"?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have been using Access database as db of choice for a long time now and this is the first time I have run into the following error message:

```
Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\dbo.mdb'
```

First, I don't have a db called dbo.mdb.

Second, the path to the db is defined in my web.config file thus:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="cingconstrng" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Roster\App_Data\AllStars.mdb" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Funniest part is that I am passing the connection string to some files without problem.

So, why is it different with this file?

Is it because I am inserting records into the db with with this file?

Any ideas is greatly appreciated. I have been working on this issue since last night and googling hasn't provided any solutions.

Comment: Check your code with a debugger. Stop where you open the connection and verify the connection string used.

Comment: Are you using any table prefixes in your insert statements?  `Insert into dbo.someTable ...`

Comment: No, @John. that's one of the weirdest things.

Comment: @John, God BLESS you. I was! Sorry didn't mean to lie. I removed them but apparently in midst of frustration, I snuck it back in there without knowing it because I was trying everything. Thank you very much sir. Very nice catch.

I don't know how you give credit here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can see this behavior if your SQL statements use namespaces:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.someTable ...
```

Remove the namespace and it should correct the issue.

Comment: Thanks again. I was going to demo this app by 1pm. Now, it is possible.

Comment: Thanks..valuble info.