# OleDbCommand ExecuteNonQuery is changing the file path to the database (Access .accdb)

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbcommand

### Error thrown only when trying to update Access DB

I have this issue I can't seem to overcome.
I have a multi-tiered WPF application that uses a MS Access database (version 2010 .accdb).
Note - I can **read** from the database with no issues.  However, when I try to update the database, the file path to the database is changed and an error thrown.

**Correct path:**
"\\hcpclrfs1w01\LakefrontShared\EmployeeInfo\EmployeeData.accdb"

**Inner Exception thrown**
OleDbException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\trice\AllDevProjects\QaDashboard\QaDashboard_Presentation\bin\Debug\dbo.mdb'.
 **Message**: *Error executing query*

After researching this issue for a few days, the closest suggestion I could find is to change the file properties field under "Copy to Output Direct" to the value *Copy if newer*.
See this [LINK](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2282340-c57e-4ba4-b2f3-24b6f45eab7c/vbnet-oledbcommand-looks-for-an-access-file-in-a-directory-other-than-where-specified?forum=vblanguage).

**Conditions List:**

- Access 2010 / 32-bit application
- Operating system - Windows 7 Enterprise / 32-bit
- VS 2017 / c#
- Tried different build configurations (Any CPU, x86)
- File properties (under Copy to Output Direct) set to Copy if newer
- Database is password protected
- Database is not imported into the project (but should not be needed)
- There are no linked tables in the database

Does anyone know a fix for this?
Below is the update method I'm using:

```
public void Update(Employee dto)
{
    AccessDao dao = new AccessDao();
    string sql = string.Format(@"UPDATE [dbo].[{0}]
        SET [EmployeeName] = @EmployeeName 
           ,[OutLookFullName] = @OutLookFullName 
           ,[EmployeeAlias] = @EmployeeAlias 
           ,[EmployeeTEAM] = @EmployeeTEAM 
           ,[SpecificTeam] = @SpecificTeam 
           ,[SpecialAssignment] = @SpecialAssignment 
           ,[EmailAddress] = @EmailAddress 
           ,[ShiftStartTime] = @ShiftStartTime 
           ,[ShiftEndTime] = @ShiftEndTime 
           ,[EmployeeSHIFT] = @EmployeeSHIFT 
           ,[JobAssignment] = @JobAssignment 
           ,[NOTES] = @NOTES 
       WHERE ID = @ID ", EmpTable);

OleDbCommand command = dao.GetAccessCommand(sql);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", dto.EmployeeName);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OutLookFullName", dto.OutlookFullName);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeAlias", dto.EmployeeAlias);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeTEAM", dto.EmployeeTeam);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SpecificTeam", dto.SpecificTeam);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SpecialAssignment", dto.SpecialAssignment);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", dto.EmailAddress);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShiftStartTime", dto.ShiftStartTime);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShiftEndTime", dto.ShiftEndTime);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeSHIFT", dto.EmployeeShift);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobAssignment", dto.JobAssignment);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOTES", dto.Notes);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", dto.EmployeeRecordId);
dao.ExecuteNonQuery(command);
}
```

The connection string is in the App.config file as follows:

```
  <add name="EmployeeCONN" 
              connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\hcpclrfs1w01\LakefrontShared\EmployeeInfo\EmployeeData.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password= password;" 
              providerName="Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" />
```

The connection and work is being done by a separate data access class as follows:

```
 public class AccessDao
    {

        //TODO: TEMP While Testing
        private const string TestConnection = "EmployeeCONN";

        #region "Database Helper Methods"            

        // Connection
        private OleDbConnection _sharedConnection;
        public OleDbConnection SharedConnection
        {
            get
            {
                if (_sharedConnection == null)
                {
                    _sharedConnection = new
                        OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[TestConnection].ConnectionString);
                }
                return _sharedConnection;
            }
            set { _sharedConnection = value; }
        }


        // Constructors
        public AccessDao() { }


   public void ExecuteNonQuery(OleDbCommand command)
        {
            try
            {
                if (command.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    command.Connection.Open();
                }
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error executing query", e);
            }
            finally
            {
                command.Connection.Close();
            }
        }

 public OleDbCommand  GetAccessCommand(string sqlQuery)
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = SharedConnection;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = sqlQuery;
            return command;
        }
```

Comment: Show the code where you are setting the "correct path".

Comment: I just edited the code info to show what you are asking for.  Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access database error "Could not find file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525477/access-database-error-could-not-find-file) - but the accepted answer to that question should work for you too.

Comment: Thank you Ciaran, I removed the [dbo]. tag from my update query and it worked!  However, I noticed that it only works in DEBUG mode.  When I try in RELEASE mode it gives the same error message as before.  Any ideas on that?

Comment: @Riceman1230 Can't help you with that I'm afraid. It's working on my machine in Release x86.

Comment: Thank you for your help Ciaran.  I'll explore why building as a release would result in an error.